# Windows batch file pass filename to vbscript

Tags: batch-file

I need to pass a file name which can have the two first characters designating the year (??_zfgli1121 the file exists with the name "20_zfgli1121" ) as an argument to a vbscript. I receive an error executing, can you please help?

```
@ECHO OFF
Set SDir=D:\Data

Set InFile=%SDir%\??_zfgli1121

IF Exist %InFile% (

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript %SDir%\Convert_SAP_Data.vbs %InFile%
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programs can handle asterisks and interrogations, others not.

An example of programs that they can't are CertUtil, CScript, WScript, Tree, and some others.
Instead, you could do

```
for %%A in (%SDir%\??_zfgli1121) do set InFile=%%A
```

and then

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript %SDir%\Convert_SAP_Data.vbs %InFile%
```

**Tip:**
Use the environment variables instead of fixed paths.
`C:\Windows` → `%SystemRoot%`. To view them take a look at `SET`

Comment: I'd use `%SystemRoot%` rather than `%windir%`…

Comment: What's the difference between `%SystemRoot%` and `%WinDir%`? In my PC they have the same path.

Comment: `%SystemRoot%` is the proper way to refer the system directory on modern Windows systems; when you look into the Registry, for instance, `%SystemRoot%` is used; `%windir%` comes from early Windows versions and is just there for backwards-compatibility reasons. Take also a look at this: [What is difference between %WinDir% and %SystemRoot%?](https://superuser.com/a/638335)